# cosine similarity plot is jumbled up with names running together

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a small list of docs for which I am plotting cosine similarity. The doc names are pretty long, I can't figure out how to keep them from running together on the plot. Here is what the file names look like:

```
['0-W909MY17R0016',
 '10 ID04160056 TOR 3.17.17',
 'ENVG',
 'FA5270-14-R-0027',
 'GSS',
 'H9240819R0001_1Oct19',
 'LCLSC16R0005',
 'LTLMII RFPFINALRELEASED',
 'N00019-15-R-2004',
 'N0010418RK032_for_PR_N0010418NB058',
 'N00164-16-R-JQ94_RFP',
 'N0025319R0001',
 'N6134019R0007_RFP',
 'N66604-18-R-0881_Conformed_Through_Amendment_0006',
 'NGLD_M_Draft_RFP_Final (3)',
 'SOL-615-16-000001_-PLSO_SOL',
 'SPRDL115R0414_0000',
 'W15QKN-18-R-0065_-_MMO',
 'W58RGZ-17-R-0211',
 'W912P618B0009_FB_FAC_SUPPORT_SVCS-_FBO',
 'W91CRB17R0004_STORM_II',
 'Full_Project_Announcement_RIK-OTA-F16EW_03_Jan_2019',
 'MQ-25 Final RFP N00019-17-R-0087',
 'Solicitation N00421-18-R-0091 - Enhanced Visual Acuity (EVA)']
```

I did a basic cosine distance between docs:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
cos_distances = cosine_distances(dtm)
mds_map = MDS(dissimilarity='precomputed')
pos = mds_map.fit_transform(cos_distances)
```

And a basic matplotlib scatterplot:

```
#pos contains the x and y coordinates of each of the documents
x = pos[:,0]
y = pos[:,1]
#we will need matplotlib to generate a scatter plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i, j, name in zip(x,y,files):
    plt.scatter(i,j)
    plt.text(i,j,name)


plt.show()
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I'm having trouble finding documentation that deals with this specifically.

Comment: Maybe you could plot each point in different color/marker and add a legend to the side of the plot?

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez yeah I could do it that way. Do you have a link to something I could do fairly easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot every point with a different color and/or marker, and create a legend to put outside the plot where you can show the filenames:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random 2D points to make scatter plot
x = [np.random.random() for i in range(len(names))]
y = [np.random.random() for i in range(len(names))]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
```

If you don't want to manually assign a color to each filename, you can map a pyplot colormap to a list of colors and use that in the scatter plot:

```
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))

for i, j, name in zip(x, y, names):
    ax.scatter(i, j, label=name, c=colors[names.index(name)])

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.6)  # This is needed so that the legend is not cut out of the figure
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

You can use the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter to move the legend around.

If you want to assign individual colors or markers, the only way I can think of doing it is by creating a dictionary. For example:

```
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))

plot_names = {'0-W909MY17R0016': [colors[0], 'o'],
              '10 ID04160056 TOR 3.17.17': [colors[1], 'x'],
              'ENVG': [colors[2], '*'],
              'FA5270-14-R-0027': [colors[3], '^']}

 for i, j, name in zip(x, y, names):
    ax.scatter(i, j, label=name, c=plot_names[name][0], marker=plot_names[name][1])

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.6)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

You can see all the available markers [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html). You can also change their sizes, borders, etc.

Comment: That does look a lot better than my original. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can give shorter names and then explain them outside the plot canvas using annotations.

Look at this stackoverflow post. 
[Python: displaying a line of text outside a matplotlib chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742511/python-displaying-a-line-of-text-outside-a-matplotlib-chart)

Comment: Thank, I'm not exactly sure how to apply this to what I'm trying to do though.